# Why do I get "borrowed value does not live long enough" error?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am writing a program in Rust that reads data from excel sheet and populates objects using that data. To convert each row of excel sheet into a `Test` object, I implemted `From<std::slice::Iter<'_, calamine::DataType>>` for `Test`.
My code looks like below.

```
use calamine::{open_workbook, DataType, Reader, Xlsx};
use std::convert::From;
use std::path::Path;
use std::slice::Iter;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Test {
    pub field1: String,
    pub field2: String,
    pub field3: String,
}

impl From<Iter<'_, calamine::DataType>> for Test {
    fn from(mut val: Iter<'_, calamine::DataType>) -> Self {
        Test {
            field1: val.next().expect("failed").to_string(),
            field2: val.next().expect("failed").to_string(),
            field3: val.next().expect("failed").to_string(),
        }
    }
}

fn read_from_excel_sheet<'a, 'b, T: From<Iter<'a, calamine::DataType>>, P: AsRef<Path>>(
    wb_path: P,
    ws_name: &'b str,
) {
    let mut workbook: Xlsx<_> = open_workbook(wb_path).expect("Cannot open wb");

    if let Some(Ok(range)) = workbook.worksheet_range(ws_name) {
        for row in range.rows().skip(1) {
            let new_item = T::from(row.iter());
        }
    }
}
```

When I complied it, I got an error.

```
error[E0597]: `range` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:31:20
   |
25 | fn read_from_excel_sheet<'a,'b, T: From<Iter<'a, calamine::DataType>>, P: AsRef<Path>>(wb_path: P, ws_name: &'b str) {
   |                          -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
29 |     if let Some(Ok(range)) = workbook.worksheet_range(ws_name) {
   |                    ----- binding `range` declared here
30 |
31 |         for row in range.rows().skip(1) {
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
32 |
33 |             let new_item = T::from(row.iter());
   |                            ------------------- argument requires that `range` is borrowed for `'a`
...
36 |     }
   |     - `range` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I can understand what the error message is saying but don't know why the lifetime of `range` matters. As the message points out, `range` will be dropped when the program reaches the end of `if` block, but at that time nothing references it because `new_item` is created and dropped in each iteration and each field of `Test` is owned type(`String`), which means it does not depend on anything.

After serveral tries, I found a soultion, but I still don't know why it works.

```
fn read_from_excel_sheet<'b, T: for<'a> From<Iter<'a, calamine::DataType>>, P: AsRef<Path>>(
    wb_path: P,
    ws_name: &'b str,
) {
    let mut workbook: Xlsx<_> = open_workbook(wb_path).expect("Cannot open wb");

    if let Some(Ok(range)) = workbook.worksheet_range(ws_name) {
        for row in range.rows().skip(1) {
            let new_item = T::from(row.iter());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With your first version the caller could call `read_from_excel_sheet::<'static, 'b, _, _>(wb_path, ws_name)` and you'd have to keep `range` around forever, but you don't do that so the compiler rejects it. Man those kind of questions are hard to find a duplicate for, though I'm sure I've come across one.

Comment: @cafce25 Do you mean that the compiler can decide a lifetime and because I did not pass a value from which the compiler can infer the lifetime for ‘a, it called the function with ‘static as a lifetime for ‘a?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter what you actually call it with, but what you *can* call it with. The compiler has to produce code that works for every lifetime `'a` (and `'b` but that doesn't matter here) so the code has to be valid with any lifetime passed in, the first variant isn't valid with every lifetime though in fact it's not valid with any lifetime from outside since all of them outlive the function call, but `range` doesn't live long enough for that.

Comment: Not related to your actual question, but is there a reason that you are implementing `From` with the specific type `slice::Iter` rather than from any `Iterator<Item = calamine::Datatype>`?

Comment: @KushagraGupta Yes, I did impermented ```From``` with ```Iterator<..>```, but as you can see from my code,  to populate ```new_item``` I passed ```row.iter()``` which was a value with a specific type. So complier raised an error saying that I passed a value to where a type paramter should be passed.